# How to initialized (or assigned) a value of an member of a structure (abstract data type) with particular default

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Here's the structure that I tried to make:

```
struct {
    char *name;
    int age;
    bool married;
} person;
```

How to initialize the married with **False** value so that every people that declared is not married in the first place until it is assigned otherwise?

Comment: In C there is no way to define default values for struct members. You need to do this during initialization of your variables. If you have a function to dynamically generate a new element of type `struct people` this function should take care about this.

Comment: If it is an abstract datatype (i.e. a datatype which can be used without knowing its specific implementation) then there should be a dedicated function for the purpose of creating a meaningfully/appropriatly initialised variable of that datatype (because otherwise questions like this one would arise and break the concept of an abstract data type). Use that function. You might be the maintainer or the creator-to-be of that/those functions, in that case fill it or modify it accordingly.

Comment: Off-topic nitpick, but `people` is plural, and this is clearly a single person (in many ways, since `married == false`), so rename to `struct person`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default value for dynamically allocated memory in C, and no built-in concept of constructor, so you need to implement setting the default values yourself. You can create a "constructor" function that does the allocation and initialisation, e.g.,

```c
struct person *new_person(const char *name, int age) {
    struct person *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    if (p) {
        p->name = strdup(name); // (subject to availability of `strdup`)
        p->age = age;
        p->married = false;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Of course in this particular case the default value is zero, so you could also just zero the memory, but with the constructor approach you can add other error checking, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function as for example

```
void default_init( struct people *person )
{
    person->name = NULL;
    person->age = 0;
    person->married = false;
}
```

And after declaring an object of the structure type

```
struct people person;
```

call the function

```
default_init( &person );
```

Or for example

```
struct people *person = malloc( sizeof( *person ) );
default_init( person );
```

Of course you could initialize an object of the structure type in the point of its declaration like for example

```
struct people person = { .name = NULL, .age = 0, .married = false };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically allocate the memory with calloc the field `married` will be false.

I would also use a *flexible array member* in the struct to allow single allocation, reallocation and free of the data. Member `age` cant be negative so more suitable type is `unsigned int`

```
struct person{
    unsigned age;
    bool married;
    char name[];
};

struct person *newPerson(const char *name, unsigned age)
{
    struct person *pr = calloc(1, sizeof(*pr) + strlen(name) + 1);
    if(pr)
    {
        strcpy(pr -> name, name);
        pr -> age = age;
    }
    return pr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An *automatic default* for non-`static` objects is not possible in C.

Recall there is no partial initialization in C: all or nothing.

Alternative's:

**Only use `static objects` that rely on zero initialization**

```
person p1; // All members filled with zero bits.

int foo() {
  static person p2;  // All members filled with zero bits.
  person p3; // No initialization.
```

**`{ 0 }`**

```
int foo() {
  person p4 = { 0 }; // First member 0, other members are 0.
```

**`{ .married = false }`**

```
int foo() {
  person p5 = { .married = false }; // .married member false, other members are 0
  person p6 = { .married = 0 }; // .married member false, other members are 0
```

**Use another object**

```
const person p_init1 = { .married = false }; // .married member false, other members are 0

int foo() {
  person p7 = p_init1
```

**`compound literal`**

```
int foo() {
  person p8 = (person){ .married = false };
```

---

***Assigning***

**`compound literal`**

```
int foo() {
  person p9;
  ...  
  p9 = (person){ .married = false }; // All members copied
```